# Not really seen - what am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Half of me is all the same.

The other half is just a proposition.

When I'm observed, I'm not really seen.

Probably because I'm in full opposition.

Hint:

> First half is about the signifier (word), second half is about the signified (object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be  :

> MIRROR

Half of me is all the same

> RRR is three times the same letter

The other half is just a proposition.

> The other letters can form IMO, acronym for "In My Opinion".

When I'm observed, I'm not really seen.

> Looking in a mirror, I rather see what's reflected than the object itself.

Probably because I'm in full opposition.

> You usually stand opposite the mirror when you observe yourself.

Comment: Exactly right!  Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

> The Moon?

Half of me is all the same:

> Two identical O's out of 4 letters

The other half is just a proposition.

> ON is a preposition... although if it's the 'other half', shouldn't that be MN?

When I'm observed, I'm not really seen:

> In a sense, you only see the sun's reflection, not light produced by the moon.

Probably because I'm in full opposition:

> Full Opposition refers to when the sun and full moon are in approximately opposite positions in the sky

Comment: Great guess, but this is not correct.